# Why is the order of execution of this test like this in TestNG?

Tags: testng

Following is the code :

```
public class Class2 {

    @Test()
    public void a() {
        System.out.println("a");    
    }
    @Test(dependsOnMethods= {"d"})
    public void b() {
        System.out.println("b");    
    }
    @Test
    public void c() {
        System.out.println("c");    
    }
    @Test
    public void d() {
        System.out.println("d");    
    }
    @Test
    public void e() {
        System.out.println("e");    
    }
}
```

The output is :

```
c
d
e
a
b
```

a) Why is the order of execution so ?
b) Why is a() executed after e() even though I haven't specified any dependsOn parameter for it?

Ideally it would be executed in the order a, c, d, b, e. Can someone please explain the logic behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as JUnit, TestNG follows an almost random execution of order (non-predictable at the very least) in it's default execution, making every test independent of each other.

TestNG introduced Test Dependencies and Test Priorities (the second also introduced in JUnit5). With this, you can set up your own order.

[Dependencies](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependent-methods) will make sure that no method that depends on another runs before that method which depends on (i.e. it will make sure that 'b' runs before 'd') and only that. The rest will follow same concept I described above.

[Priorities](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations) will give an ALMOST actual order to your tests, specifying which one you want to run first. Why 'almost'? Cause if test B has priority 1 and test D has priority 2, D will still run first because B has a dependency on it, and otherwise will fail.

I hope this answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But if i don't write depends on , it will run by alphabetical order of the methods. Why isn't that happening on writing dependency ?

Comment: I think it's just the fact that testng is not trying to give an order by default, the fact that before it was being ran in order, could be just a mere accident. The framework might have a reason to change the order or to randomize when you add test dependency.
Anyway, looking a little bit more for an answer to your question, I found this:
https://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/preserve-order-in-testng

Maybe you can play with it and see if you can achieve something similar to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

TestNG - @Test dependency works only with other tests that belongs to the same class or in any one of the inherited classes but not across different classes.